Chess and Axioms Of Probability
N(x, y) ≤ 10
N(x, y): The number of moves the black king can make to reach to the square (x,y).
x,y: Coordinates of a square on a chessboard.
Game: Chess game with special rules*
*Special rules of the game:

The white bishop cannot move.

A black horse can move like an elephant.

The white king can move like the queen


Law:

In any chess game starting with the standard starting position, the black king reaches the safe square in 10 moves at most.


This is how the board looks like and what is required is that no matter what the opponent's opening move is in N squares, you will find that he cannot attack after "a" (number) of moves.
Is the "law" true or wrong?

Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

The second-to-last paragraph is a little confusing (perhaps there is a typo). Also, what is the point of special rules (1) and (2) if those pieces don't exist? Thanks.

Also, your "law" refers to "the standard starting position" but the position you show is nonstandard. Please clarify

This is all very unclear. Are you asking if the black king can reach any square safely within at most ten moves given these rules? This is clearly false (for every square in row 1 for instance). But if not, what are the "safe squares" you had in mind?

@TimSeifert Replace the black horses with two elephants. The required thing is to prove the truth or falsehood of this law which says that after ten moves or less the king will be in coordinates where the other pieces cannot give him a checkmate

Isn't that trivial? The king starts being unable to be mated, so the condition is satisfied after 0 moves.
